# how to upload a file and a text Form on same page, django

Tags: post, django-models, django-views, django-forms, python-requests

**I want to upload a file and text from the same page to two Modals.** I have created two forms on the same page, one is `type=file` and the other one is `type=text`.And two separate `button`'s for each form. And created two Modal  `Gallery_img` and  `Gallery_txt`. when I upload a file, it successfully get uploaded but when I then upload text its is showing error( mentioned below )

Iam Getting error:  **MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file'**

Form:

```
        <form id='form1' action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='file' name='file'>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" onclick='submitForm1()'>Ok</button>
        </form>
        <br>
        <form  id='form2' action="" method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='text' name='text'>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" onclick='submitForm2()'> Okay</button>
        </form>

//scripts for buttons

<script>
        function submitForm1(){
            document.getElementById('form1').submit();
        };
        function submitForm2(){
            document.getElementById('form2').submit();
        };

    </script>
```

Modals:

```
class Gallery_img(models.Model):
    gallery_image =  models.ImageField( upload_to='img',max_length=None)

    
class Gallery_txt(models.Model):
    gallery_text = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True)
```

Views:

```
def gallery(request):
    from .models import Gallery_img, Gallery_txt 
    if request.method== 'POST':
        if request.FILES['file']:
            post = Gallery_img()
            post.gallery_image = request.FILES['file']
            post.save()
            print('successful image uplaod')

            return render(request, 'gallery.html')
        
        if request.POST.get('text'):
            post= Gallery_txt()
            post.gallery_text = request.POST.get('text')
            post.save()
            print('successful text uplaod')
            return render(request, 'gallery.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'gallery.html')
```

Comment: Guys I got the answer on my own. It will be >request.FILES.get('file')

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the `views.py`

```
post.gallery_image = request.FILES.get('file')
```

Comment: This correct answer, just change '[ ]' to ' ( )'  and place a get befor3 ' ( ) '.